# Smart Unwrapped UV Islands

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I'm trying to get a list of the bounding boxes of UV islands after a smart unwrap, but the list that's getting returned doesn't make sense to me.

Here's my code for getting the islands:

```
# Selecting Object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj_object
obj_object.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=True)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="SELECT")

# Creating and Getting UV Map
uvmap = obj_object.data.uv_layers.get("UVMap")
if not uvmap:
    uvmap = obj_object.data.uv_layers.new(name="UVMap")
uvmap.active = True

# Unwrapping and Getting Islands
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=55, island_margin=0.1)
islands = mesh_utils.mesh_linked_uv_islands(obj_object.data)
```

What I'm expecting to be returned is a list of islands corresponding to the UV Map I get from the smart unwrap. What I seem to get is entirely different. It seems like random collections of polygons unrelated to the smart unwrapped UV. This is on Blender version 2.93 if that makes any difference.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It seems that "*mesh_linked_uv_islands*" doesn't work in edit mode. Also is "*angle_limit=55*" **radians** correct?

Comment: True, I changed it later. I get the same result though sadly

Comment: I got a list of the island, [[0, 1, 4, 2, 3], [5]]. It matched what the editor showed. Please show me, using a diagram, what did not match in your case.